# any asp.net control for displaying directory structure and bookmarking files location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need a control I could use in asp.net mvc for browsing imported directory  structure for selecting files but also to be able to setup a bookmarks on one side for quick access. I have seen such control in devexpress but without bookmarking option, anybody has seen such feature somewhere?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

for a very simple solution i recommend the usage of a TreeView.

Addons like a bookmarking Option, can be written easily by yourself.

Tutorials for TreeViews can be found all over the web.
Here's just an Example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/696985/How-to-Create-TreeView-in-MVC